# What is the meaning of "the key to democracy"

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the key of democracy in below sentence?

By passing on expert opinion to the public, it becomes **the key to democracy in the hands of informed and participating citizens**. It explains to people the flaws in the existing system and makes it easier for the people to make intelligent decision about public affairs. This it protects the democratic interests of the people.

Source of info

[image]

Comment: Remember to add the source for the quote!!!

Comment: Thank you for adding a picture. Nevertheless, [proper source referencing](/help/referencing) requires a link, or the name of the book and the author.

Answer (score 0):

Key: metaphorically, the critical part that enables something to function.  A key to a door enables it to open.  A car key starts the car.

So the key to democracy is the critical thing that enables a country to be democratic.

Unfortunately you have cut the quote off, but I guess it is "the media" that "passes expert opinion to the public". So I think the author claims that "the media" is the key to democracy.

Comment: Can you rephrase this sentence in simple wording? *By passing on expert opinion to the public, it becomes the key to democracy in the hands of informed and participating citizens*

Comment: By passing on expert opinion to the public, it becomes an important aspect of democracy in the hands of informed and participating citizens.